# Console display in C++ for cross platform

Tags: c++, cross-platform, console-application

Using C++ for a cross platform console app, is there any way to implement a display which is static and dynamically changing, rather than an output which prints under the previous output? I.e. For a simple board game, rather than reprinting the board each turn, update a single output.

Edit: AFAIK, unicode is not entirely necessary, I am using only characters which appear on a standard EN-GB keyboard.

I'll look into NCURSES, although I was wondering if there something within the C++ standard which could help me achieve this. Call me ignorant if you like, but I'm just wondering.

Comment: You could look into something like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). I think there is libraries for Windows.

Comment: Question #1: is unicode support required?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [NCURSES](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) is what you're looking for. Terminal wrapper for ConsoleUI, which is cross-platform. It allows you to write to a virtual screen buffer, and control when and how the refresh is being done. It does internal book-keeping of that buffer and will only refresh the characters which changed. Curses was designed in days where connection speed mattered so terminal refresh operations were being done in a smart way.

There's an ncurses tag at SO, so you'll find a lot of information here about the gritty details.

Comment: Amending this by noting that you'll have to use [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) or similar on Windows. It works almost exactly like ncurses, though, so mostly linker parameters would have to be changed.

Comment: So, there would be no entirley cross-platform implementation? Is the only way to achieve this using seperate libs for different platforms?

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you could use cygwin under Windows, unless you really need to use the genuine Windows console.

Comment: pdcurses is an implementation of curses, with ncurses being the "new" curses, but in reality they all behave essentially the same way and have the same functionality down to function prototypes. Porting would mean just changing <pdcurses.h> to <ncurses.h> (don't quote me on those header names :p) and changing the library to link against.